# Forgot Password in xmpp openfire

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, forgot-password

I am making an chat application using xmpp with openfire using smack. Now I want to ask one question here that Can I implement forgot password functionality in the same. I have searched the internet some say yes some say no, but no one has provided me a stable solution.

please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That would really be dependent on how you implement/configure authentication.  To my knowledge, XMPP has no such feature.

The simplest approach would probably be to use some tool that already has this feature for creating and managing your users, preferably in some standard repository like LDAP.  Then just make Openfire use LDAP for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Much depends on what you used as the database backend.  You'll have to learn about whichever database it is.  If it's MySQL or Postgres, it should be pretty simple to do with Perl.  If it's the built-in database, not so sure.

You may want to consider the question: how do you ensure that the person who says they need to reset their password is who they say they are (not lying)?